# How do I parameterize limit?

Tags: python-3.x, db2, prepared-statement

I cannot bind the limit parameters in my statement.  How can I accomplish this?

```
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("")
sql = "SELECT * FROM my.table where id = ? limit ?, 100"
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql)
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 1, 50)
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 2, 50)
ibm_db.execute(stmt)
```

Is there an issue converting the bind parameter in the limit field to an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("")
sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT T.*, ROWNUMBER() OVER() RN FROM my.table T where id = ?) WHERE RN BETWEEN ? AND ? + 100"
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql)
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 1, 50)
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 2, 50)
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 3, 50)
ibm_db.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: Well it seems my error might not even have anything to do with this. I keep getting a Segmentation Fault: 11